# running an app and it crash

Tags: android, windows, android-activity, crash, fatal-error

hi when i click on launch my app, the first page comes up, when i want to navigate to my next page the app stop works and give me this error:

```
Process: com.example.arel0002.pizzeria, PID: 4215
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.arel0002.pizzeria/com.example.arel0002.pizzeria.pizza}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Comment: Show your code and Have you define the activity in your manifest??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Your Activity in Manifest to which you want to go

Like this

```html
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".mainpage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 
  <activity
            android:name="com.example.arel0002.pizzeria.pizza"
          >
        </activity>
 
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.arel0002.pizzeria.erbjudanden"
            >
        </activity>
  <activity
            android:name="com.example.arel0002.pizzeria.omoss"
            >
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79670/discussion-on-answer-by-rishi-paul-running-an-app-and-it-crash).

Answer (score 2):

Did you read this:

```
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You need to declare your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

In your Manifest declare like this

```
<activity  android:name=".YourActivityName"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Here `.YourActivityName` is your Activity name

Comment: there is a typo: .Compte different from .Compare; the dot in .Compte works if package="com.example.etc" in the manifest is the same of .Compte class

Answer (score 1):

*Declare your activity in (AndroidManifest.xml)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".mainpage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```